# Need sales data archived for certain period Magento 1.7

Tags: magento-1.7

We are working for eCommerce site which have huge traffic and Orders tables like `sales_flat_order`,`sales_flat_order_grid`,`sales_flat_invoice` have more then 3 lakh records.

There are running cron in the system which export the orders to back office support and this cron runs in every 15 min. The problem is that when there are huge traffic in the site the crons become jam. So can anybody help me to suggest that why this happening. Is this need to clean the database or anything else we need to do to overcome this problem.

Comment: Knowing a bit more about the export cron and what it does, how it works, will be helpfull

Answer (score 4):

Magento EE (Enterprise Edition) has an order archive module that comes with it. The CE (Community Edition) does not. There are some modules available that provide this functionality I believe, but I haven't tried them and wouldn't want to suggest any because of that.

All in all, 300k orders (or database rows) isn't that many. Perhaps you don't need an archive so much as look at your processes to speed them up.